# Reverse for 'edit-todo' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit\\-todo/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've dug around the internet and can't find a solution. Please help me lovely people of the internet.

**In my views.py**

```py
@login_required
def edit_todo(request, pk):
    usertodo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=pk)
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

**In my urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('edit-todo/<int:pk>/', views.edit_todo, name='edit-todo'),
    path('test/<int:pk>/', views.edit_todo, name='test'),
    ...
]
```

**In my template/component that's included**

```html
<form hx-encoding="multipart/form-data" hx-post="{% url 'core:edit-todo' tododetail.todo.id %}" hx-target="#todo-list" method="post">
```

`tododetail.todo.id` is called because I've got an ordering table which has `todo` & `user` as foreign keys.

When accessing the view directly using a test URL it works

[image: test url]

Comment: Does `{% url 'core:test' tododetail.todo.id %}` work?

Comment: The `tododetail.todo.id` variable is empty... Try to debug why `tododetail.todo.id` has not the expected value !!!

Comment: @Rvector, variable is not empty. When I add it to template it displays.

Comment: @xyres, 'core:test' has the same error.